# Create a Login Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that I want to provide some security on, but up to this point I've only created one form that does all of my work.  I want to create a new form that pops up in front of my main form right when the application launches.  Then validates the password entered against a MySQL database.  I have all of the MySQL stuff down, but wondering how to make another form pop up in front of my main form which disables the main form, waits for the password form to validate, then disappears once the form is validated and lets the user perform their work.  I'll also need to transfer the authenticated user's info back to my main form.

Comment: Why not just use a modal form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new form and then use the [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) function. If you show the form from your main form it will be displayed in a modal fashion.

Create this in a login style and close the form if the user is authenticated or show an error if the username and password are incorrect.

From MSDN:

```
public void ShowMyDialogBox()
{
   Form2 testDialog = new Form2();

   // Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
   if (testDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      // Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox.
      this.txtResult.Text = testDialog.TextBox1.Text;
   }
   else
   {
      this.txtResult.Text = "Cancelled";
   }
   testDialog.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: +1 for using ShowDialog(): @muncherelli: The important difference between the Show() and ShowDialog() is that the ShowDialog() forces the user to respond to the window that opens up, they cannot minimise it and continue using the application. Show() allows the user to continue using the main application.

Comment: Do I put this in my Form1_Load method?

Comment: Are you adding a login button? Or do you just want it to pop up automatically? You should ensure that the form has completed loading before you display it. This link tells you the order of events for a Windows Form: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx

Comment: I don't see where to put this code so it displays after the form loads.  If I put it in Form1_Load, the box pops up before the form is displayed.  I would rather have it in the foreground (model) of the main form.

Comment: Form.Shown is the final event to fire when the form is being constructed and rendered. Form.Shown is fired when the form is actually displayed. Try handling the Form.Shown event and adding the code in that function

Comment: +1 The `this` in `testDialog.ShowDialog(this)` is important... In my case, my main form would load without showing the login form. It was because I had `testDailog.ShowDialog()`. Note, in my code I did not have `this`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [ApplicationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext.aspx) for this kind of log on form <--> shell form switching behavior.

Your main method:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new MyFancyContext());
}
```

And an implementation for `MyFancyContext`:

```
public class MyFancyContext : ApplicationContext
{
    private LogOnForm logOnForm;

    private ShellForm shellForm;

    public MyFancyContext()
    {
        this.logOnForm = new LogOnForm();
        this.MainForm = this.logOnForm;
    }

    protected override void OnMainFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.MainForm == this.logOnForm
            && this.logOnForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Assume the log on form validated credentials
            this.shellForm = new ShellForm();
            this.MainForm = this.shellForm;
            this.MainForm.Show();  
        }
        else
        {
            // No substitution, so context will stop and app will close
            base.OnMainFormClosed(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

The `MainForm` is the form that is currently receiving messages.

The advantage of this type of setup is that if you want to do things like hide the shell form after some idle timeout and redisplay the log on form, we have one class where this functionality takes place.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [showdialog(loginform)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx) from the main form's constructor and return true if successful or change the startup for to the login form before the main form loads.  Show dialog is modal.